# position a picture in the middle

Tags: css, image, xhtml

I (absolute beginner) would like to put an image into a box with a little margin around. I tried with padding and so, didn't work. Then I tried this:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #CC6699; width:11em; height:5.5em;">
    <img style="align:center; width:10em; height:5em;" src="path">
</div>
```

But instead the image gets stuck in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways to do this:

My usual is to set a background image instead.

In your css:

```
div#img_container {
    background: url(images/myImage.png) center center
}
```

In your html:

```
<div id="img_container"></div>
```

Or to just put some padding around it in your CSS

```
img#myImage {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<img id="myImage" src="images/myImage.png" />
```

Comment: The first suggestion is only appropriate if he's talking about a decorative image of some sort; if it's an image that's actually part of the content, don't do this. The second would probably be better done with margins.

Comment: Went with padding cause he said he tried that.  But you're right, on both accounts.

Answer (score 2):

CSS level 2 doesn't have a property for centering things vertically. There will probably be one in CSS level 3. But even in CSS2 you can center blocks vertically, by combining a few properties. The trick is to specify that the outer block is to be formatted as a table cell, because the contents of a table cell can be centered vertically.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #CC6699; width:11em; height:5.5em;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;">
    <img style="width:10em; height:5em;" src="path">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

As rpflo suggests, using the background-position property is especially great if the container happens to be smaller than the image. Just remember to include the "background-repeat:none" style if you don't want the image to be tiled.

Comment: Keep in mind that later in your css life display:table-cell won't play nicely with other styles (like floating).

Comment: I agree with rpflo - not a good solution.
Tables are for Tables and not for design.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#wrap {
width: 500px;
text-align: center;
}
.pic {
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="logo.gif" class="pic">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following small jQuery plugin. It centers the loading image in the middle of the specified container (vertically and horizontally): 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/CenterImage

Demo site: 
http://www.demosites.somee.com/demos/centerimage.html

Usage: This plugin positions a loading image centrally over a specified html container (div, span...).

Currently available configuration settings:

```
{ path: "../Images/ajax.gif", overlayColor: 'green', opacity: 0.2, zindex: 2000, isrelative:true }
```

Minimum configuration for initialization:

```
$('.4th').CenterImage({ path: "../Images/ajax-bar.gif" });
```

Call this, in order to remove the loading image (and the overlay)

```
$('.4th').CenterImage('remove');
```

Comment: Note that while this may be a working solution, the OP marked the question with CSS tag and not jQuery.